# Generating statistics on a command with totcount

Tags: totcount

I have a document that looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass{report}                                                                                                                                                                  

\begin{document}

\section{A}                                                                                                            
\subsection{a}                                                                                                                                                                                                       
\element\element                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
\subsection{b}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
\element\element\element                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
\subsection{c}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
\element\element\element\element                                                                                                                                                                                                             

\section{B}
\subsection{a}
\element\element
\subsection{b}
\element

\end{document}
```

in which I redefined the `section` and `subsection` macros as well as define an `\element` macro. They all take several parameters to format the output but I think that is irrelevant to solve the problem here so I left the first parameter only i.e. the name of the section/subsection.

I want to sum the usage of the `\element` macro across sections and subsections and record those statistics to a log file. So for the given instance, the output should be:

```latex
9
2
3
4
3
2
1
```

Using the `totcount` package, I first tried to create two variables `\sectionname` and `\subsectionname` and then create a counter based on the concatenation of those two `\newtotcounter{c\sectionname\subsectionname}` during the evaluation of `\section` and `\subsection`. However, only the last section and subsection are correctly counted, `-1` is printed for the rest, indicating that the counter is not incremented at all. This is also indicated by the fact that the `.aux` file generated during the first compilation only lists the last two counters. Looking at the code of the package I noticed the use of a `\AtEndDocument` macro and then assumed that only the last section and subsection were kept because this macro would not see the updated name each time the `\section` and `\subsection` macros would be called. Thus I moved to creating a different counter for each section and subsection:

```latex
\usepackage{totcount}

\newwrite\statsfile
\immediate\openout\statsfile=stats.txt

\newcounter{sectionid}
\newcounter{subsectionid}

\newcommand{\createsectioncounter}{
  \stepcounter{sectionid}
  \newtotcounter{sec\roman{sectionid}}
}
\newcommand{\createsubsectioncounter}{
  \stepcounter{subsectionid}
  \newtotcounter{subsec\roman{subsectionid}}
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \createsectioncounter
  \immediate\write\statsfile{\number\totvalue{sec\roman{sectionid}}}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
  \createsubsectioncounter
  \immediate\write\statsfile{\number\totvalue{subsec\roman{subsectionid}}}
}

\newcommand{\element}{
  \stepcounter{sec\roman{sectionid}}

  \makeatletter
  \ifcsname c@subsec\roman{subsectionid}\endcsname
  \stepcounter{subsec\roman{subsectionid}}
  \fi
  \makeatother
}
```

This outputs:

```
-1
-1
-1
-1
3
-1
1
```

which clearly suffers the same problem. The `.aux` file content is:

```latex
\relax 
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@secii@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{secii@totc}\fi\setcounter{secii@totc}{3}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@subsecv@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{subsecv@totc}\fi\setcounter{subsecv@totc}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@subsecv@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{subsecv@totc}\fi\setcounter{subsecv@totc}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@subsecv@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{subsecv@totc}\fi\setcounter{subsecv@totc}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@secii@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{secii@totc}\fi\setcounter{secii@totc}{3}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@subsecv@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{subsecv@totc}\fi\setcounter{subsecv@totc}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@subsecv@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{subsecv@totc}\fi\setcounter{subsecv@totc}{1}
```

How can I achieve this behavior and not have totcount only take the last counter into account ?

Note: I am not interested in outputting the statistics to a PDF.

Note: I am aware of the `totalcount` package but don't see how it could help. I would be happy to use it if it were to solve the problem though.

Comment: I am not using chapters because my document is more of a database than a classic document that I print using `flacards` so it makes more sense to divide it into sections rather than chapters. What I presented is an excerpt from the original document that I find easier to work on to solve this issue. Just for more clarification, a subsection should count every `\element` before the next subsection; a section should count every `\element` before the next section, including those within enclosed subsections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `expl3` answer with an incremental approach where the element counts are stored in a property list (i.e., a key-value array) with the (sub)section numbers as keys. The functionality is largely the same as the other answer (a small difference is that subsections without elements are counted as 0) but the implementation is perhaps a bit closer to the original MWE.

There are four integer variables, two for the section and subsection numbering and two for counting the number of elements for the current section and subsection. The counts are stored in an array of the form `section_stats_prop[section_number] = number_of_elements`. Inside `\element` the values are increased. If an element is added within the same section or subsection the value in the array is overwritten.

At the end the values are written to a text file. The key-value array can be printed using `\prop_map_inline`, however the order of the values is not guaranteed. Therefore a separate list is stored with just the (sub)section numbers in order. This list is used to provide the keys to print the key-value array.

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newwrite\statsfile
\immediate\openout\statsfile=stats.txt

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_section_stats_prop   % array with counts
\seq_new:N \g_section_numbers_seq   % array with (sub)section numbers 
\int_new:N \g_sec_count             % section counter
\int_new:N \g_subsec_count          % subsection counter
\int_new:N \g_current_sec           % elements in current section
\int_new:N \g_current_subsec        % elements in current subsection

\RenewDocumentCommand\section{m}{
    \int_incr:N \g_sec_count        % increase section counter
    \int_zero:N \g_subsec_count     % set subsection counter to 0
    \int_zero:N \g_current_sec      % set section element counter to 0
    \int_zero:N \g_current_subsec   % set subsection element counter to 0
    % store section number in array of (sub)section numbers
    \seq_put_right:NV \g_section_numbers_seq {\g_sec_count}
    % initialize counts array for this section to 0
    \prop_gput:NVn \g_section_stats_prop {\g_sec_count}{0}
}

\RenewDocumentCommand\subsection{m}{
    \int_incr:N \g_subsec_count     % increase subsection counter
    \int_zero:N \g_current_subsec   % set subsection element counter to 0
    % compose subsection number as section-subsection
    \str_set:Nx \g_seccn_str {\int_use:N \g_sec_count - \int_use:N \g_subsec_count}
    % store subsection number in array of (sub)section numbers
    \seq_put_right:NV \g_section_numbers_seq {\g_seccn_str}
    % initialize counts array for this subsection to 0
    \prop_gput:NVn \g_section_stats_prop {\g_seccn_str}{0}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\element{}{
    \int_incr:N \g_current_sec          % increase element counter for section
    \int_incr:N \g_current_subsec       % increase element counter for subsection
    % overwrite counts array for this section with new value
    \prop_gput:NVV \g_section_stats_prop {\g_sec_count}{\g_current_sec}
    % compose subsection number
    \str_set:Nx \g_seccn_str {\int_use:N \g_sec_count - \int_use:N \g_subsec_count}
    % overwrite counts array for this subsection with new value
    \prop_gput:NVV \g_section_stats_prop {\g_seccn_str}{\g_current_subsec}
}

% print counts array to file using order of (sub)section number array
\NewDocumentCommand{\printseq}{}{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_section_numbers_seq {
    \immediate\write\statsfile{##1:\space\prop_item:Nn \g_section_stats_prop {##1}}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\section{A}
\element
\subsection{a}
\element\element
\subsection{b}
\element\element\element
\subsection{c}
\element\element\element\element
\section{B}
\subsection{a}
\element\element
\subsection{b}
\element
\subsection{c}

\printseq
\end{document}
```

`stats.txt`:

```
1: 10
1-1: 2
1-2: 3
1-3: 4
2: 3
2-1: 2
2-2: 1
2-3: 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming just sections and subsections, my idea is to define `\element` so that it stores the status of section/subsection when it is called in a sequence.

At end document, the sequence is processed to get totals.

Each item is of the form `{<section>}{<subsection>}` and I map the sequence once for each section; for items matching the current section index, I increment the counter and also set an intarray item for the corresponding subsection.

At the end of the job a line is written on the terminal for each section and each subsection where `\element` appears, with the number of entries. The same information is written out in the `.aux` file, from where it can be easily retrieved.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\realelement}{I'm an element}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\element}{}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_element_section_seq { {\arabic{section}}{\arabic{subsection}} }
  \realelement
 }
\AtEndDocument{\__element_process:}

\seq_new:N \g_element_section_seq
\int_new:N \l__element_section_int
\int_new:N \l__element_subsection_int
\intarray_new:Nn \g__element_subsection_intarray { 1000 } 

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__element_process:
 {
  \int_step_inline:nn { \value{section} }
   {
    \__element_process_section:n { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__element_process_section:n
 {
  \int_zero:N \l__element_section_int
  \int_zero:N \l__element_subsection_int
  \intarray_gzero:N \g__element_subsection_intarray
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_element_section_seq
   {
    \__element_process_item:nnn { #1 } ##1
   }
  \__element_write_section:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__element_process_item:nnn
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__element_section_int
    \int_compare:nT { #3 > \l__element_subsection_int }
     {
      \int_set:Nn \l__element_subsection_int { #3 }
     }
    \intarray_gset:Nnn \g__element_subsection_intarray { #3 }
     { \intarray_item:Nn \g__element_subsection_intarray { #3 } + 1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__element_write_section:n
 {
  \typeout{Section~#1:~\int_to_arabic:n { \l__element_section_int } }
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
   {
    \token_to_str:N \elementsection {#1} { \int_to_arabic:n { \l__element_section_int } }
   }
  \int_step_inline:nn { \l__element_subsection_int }
   {
    \typeout{Subsection~#1.##1:~\intarray_item:Nn \g__element_subsection_intarray { ##1 }}
    \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
     {
      \token_to_str:N \elementsubsection {#1} {##1} { \intarray_item:Nn \g__element_subsection_intarray { ##1 } }
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\elementsection}{mm}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\elementsubsection}{mmm}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\subsection{a}
\element\element
\subsection{b}
\element\element\element
\subsection{c}
\element\element\element\element

\section{B}
\subsection{a}
\element\element
\subsection{b}
\element

\end{document}
```

The output on the terminal will be

```
Section 1: 9
Subsection 1.1: 2
Subsection 1.2: 3
Subsection 1.3: 4
Section 2: 3
Subsection 2.1: 2
Subsection 2.2: 1
```

In the `.aux` file we'll have

```latex
\elementsection{1}{9}
\elementsubsection{1}{1}{2}
\elementsubsection{1}{2}{3}
\elementsubsection{1}{3}{4}
\elementsection{2}{3}
\elementsubsection{2}{1}{2}
\elementsubsection{2}{2}{1}
```